# How to get the count of FB friends my friends have?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Now my app is seeking the following permissions from user.

**user_about_me,user_birthday,email, friends_about_me,friends_relationships**

I'm getting the friends of the current logged in user and their relationship status. Is there any way to get the total count of FB friends for each one of them (i.e. No of FB friends my friends have) . I don't need the friends list but its enough to get the total no of FB friends a FB user have.

Is that possible?  I know that if the user haven't authorized the app we couldn't find any information. But i guess the no of friends a FB user has may be a public data!!(unless he has privacy setting over them also)..

Is that possible using any FQL queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution myself. Its possible to use the **FQL** to get the friends count.

There is a **friend_count** field against the user table.

```
SELECT uid, name, friend_count 
FROM user 
WHERE 
uid IN
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

The above query will retrieve all my friends with their names and their friend_count.